# how to prevent debugger from taking focus when you evalute lisp expresison with errors

Tags: debugging, focus

How to reproduce:

1. write some faulty elisp code
2. press `C-x C-e` for `eval-last-sexp`
3. the debugger will appear  (`*backtrace*` window) and take the focus of the cursor.

I'd like the focus to remain with the original window so. How can I do that?

Comment: I'm sure there is some way to do this, but why would you want to?

Comment: I have a `close-and-kill-next-pane` function defined in my `.init`. I use that to kill windows that I just needed temporarily, help docs, etc. After I identify the issue, I want to close the debugger and work on my code. By habbit,i hit the keybinding for `close-and-kill-next-pane` and instead of the debugger going away, what i was working on goes away. Does that make sense? Please tell me if that workflow doesn't make sense. I'm new to writing elisp code.

Comment: When the *Backtrace* window is displayed, Emacs entered what is called `recursive-edit`.  It is possible to remain in `recursive-edit` and do other things; however, it is usually a good idea to deal with the bug while you have the debugger window open.  The debugger window can be closed with the letter `q` when focus is in that debugging buffer, and that exits `recursive-edit`.  There are other ways to exit `recursive-edit`, but the `q` key is generally the most convenient (in my opinion).

Comment: Please add some of what you put in your comment to the question, as the rationale/motivation for the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the sequencing is a bit tricky as mentioned in the comment below, but reselecting the previous window seems like the easiest way:

```el
(defun my-debug-hook ()
  ;; Selecting the window in `debug-mode-hook' is too early, it will
  ;; confuse the debugger's code, causing it to replace the current
  ;; buffer contents with the backtrace, and reset `buffer-undo-list'!
  ;; We want to do it when the debugger enters a `recursive-edit'.
  ;; The (recursive) command loop will call `post-command-hook' once
  ;; at startup, which is exactly the right time for us.
  (add-hook 'post-command-hook #'select-previous-window-once))

(defun select-previous-window-once ()
  (select-window (previous-window))
  (remove-hook 'post-command-hook #'select-previous-window-once))

(add-hook 'debugger-mode-hook #'my-debug-hook)
```

Comment: when I add the code above to my `.init`, it does not change the `*backtrace*` window still takes focus when evaulating lisp code with errors

Comment: @WickedJargon hmm, worked for me. What Emacs version are you running?

Comment: I solved it. My apologies. Your code works

Answer (score 0):

In your comment you say this:

> I have a `close-and-kill-next-pane` function defined in my `.init`. I use that to kill windows that I just needed temporarily, help docs, etc.
>
> After I identify the issue, I want to close the debugger and work on my code. By habit, I hit the keybinding for `close-and-kill-next-pane` and instead of the debugger going away, what I was working on goes away. Does that make sense? *Please tell me if that workflow doesn't make sense.*

My answer is to tell you that that workflow doesn't make much sense, to me, at least. I'd say that it is better to get out of that habit, or at least to temper it enough to take a quick look at the `*Backtrace*` (debugger) window, to see what's going on.

The debugger window is selected by default so you can address the error. What you really want to do, if you're uninterested in what it tells you or you've already taken a look at it, is to dismiss the debugger by hitting **`q`**. That *exits the recursive edit* that was entered. (Just deleting the window does *not* exit the recursive edit.)

If, for some reason, the debugger window is no longer selected, you can still exit the recursive edit (without bothering to select that window and use `q`).  You can use **`C-]`**, which is `abort-recursive-edit`, or **`C-M-c`**, which is `exit-recursive-edit`, from anywhere.

Comment: "(Just deleting the window does not exit the recursive edit.)" - but killing the buffer does, and I would guess that @WickedJargon's `close-and-kill-next-pane` command does kill the buffer (otherwise it would be called `close-next-pane`).

Answer (score 0):

At the end of your configuration, put `(setq inhibit-debugger t)`, this will inhibit debugger completely.

Be aware that inhibit-debugger will ignore any value on typical vars such as `debug-on-error`, etc.; or the function `debug-on-entry`. So, when you want to debug, undo the `inhibit-debugger` var!

My motivation was to avoid having a non responsive Emacs terminal, which, after doing *abort recursive stuff*, ended up "introducing characters", which depends on how they interact with current mode could be harm stuff. And the worst part of it, is when you are doing things very fast and you did not realize what happened.